# Timeout error when I try to delete a collection in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am trying to delete a collection in MarkLogic via Query Console using the `xdmp:collection-delete` function but I am getting a timeout exception:

> SVC-EXTIME: xdmp:collection-delete("") -- Time limit exceeded"

The collection contains about 150,000 documents and are small documents. Can someone help?

The time is set to 3600 in the admin console.I tried using the xdmp:spawn-function to delete it in batches,but i am getting a syntax error:

> "unexpected Lbrace_, expecting Comma_ or Rpar_": xquery version "0.9-ml" define variable $uriMatch as xs:string {"/sortkey-257-2019*"} let $_ := for $uri in cts:uri-match($uriMatch) return if(doc-available($uri)) then (xdmp:spawn-function(function(){ xdmp:collection-delete(xdmp:document-get-collections($uri)),xdmp:commit()} ,  update  )) else () return $_

PFB, the query that is returning XDMP:MAX-TASKS exception:
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $uriMatch:="/snapshot-257-2019*"

for $uri in cts:uri-match($uriMatch)
  return
   if(fn:doc-available($uri)) then
     let $x:=
    xdmp:spawn-function(function(){
          xdmp:collection-delete(xdmp:document-get-collections($uri)),xdmp:commit()},
          
          update
          )
      return $x
    else
    xdmp:log("No documents in collection")

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different approaches to working around the SVC-EXTIME issue.

1. Change the time out settings for the transaction or request (depending on how the call is being made).

[`xdmp:set-request-time-limit(3600)`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:set-request-time-limit)

or:

[`xdmp:set-transaction-time-limit(3600)`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:set-transaction-time-limit)

2. Break the delete up into batches
3. Use [CoRB](https://developer.marklogic.com/code/corb/) to perform the delete

Comment: The time is set to 3600 in the admin console.I tried using the xdmp:spawn-function to delete it in batches,but i am getting a syntax error,"unexpected Lbrace_, expecting Comma_ or Rpar_":  
xquery version "0.9-ml"
define variable $uriMatch as xs:string {"/sortkey-257-2019*"}
let $_ := for $uri in cts:uri-match($uriMatch)
   return if(doc-available($uri)) then 
(xdmp:spawn-function(function(){
  xdmp:collection-delete(xdmp:document-get-collections($uri)),xdmp:commit()}
 ,
<options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
  <transaction-mode>update</transaction-mode>
</options>
))
 else ()     
return $_

Comment: @rohithsuresh That is a typical syntax error message, meaning the query is not correct.  Try editing your question to add your query, and we may be able help you fix it.

Comment: Hi,
I have fixed the syntax error . When i run the query, i am getting an error XDMP-MAXTASKS-- Task server exceeded maximum number of tasks-100000. But the next day i see some documents deleted. I just to understand how a function can return error and still delete documents @Michael Gardner

Comment: @rohithsuresh The query is spawning tasks that are being executed.  The tasks are being performed as individual transactions, so some will complete prior to hitting the MAXTASKS message.  Unless you post your query in the question, we can't really help you resolve the issue.

Comment: I have posted the query